# How to generate flamegraphs from macOS process samples?

Tags: macos, sample, macos-monterey, dtrace, flamegraph

Anyone have a clean process for converting samples on macOS to [FlameGraphs](https://github.com/brendangregg/FlameGraph)?

After a bit of fiddling I thought I could perhaps use a tool such as [`flamegraph-sample`](https://github.com/brc7/flamegraph-sample), but it seems to give me some trouble and so I thought perhaps there may be other more up-to-date options that I'm missing insomuch that this tool gives an error:

```
$ sudo sample PID -file ~/tmp/sample.txt -fullPaths 1
Sampling process 198 for 1 second with 1 millisecond of run time between samples
Sampling completed, processing symbols...
Sample analysis of process 35264 written to file ~/tmp/sample.txt

$ python stackcollapse-sample.py ~/tmp/sample.txt > ~/tmp/sample_collapsed.txt

$ flamegraph.pl ~/tmp/sample_collapsed.txt > ~/tmp/sample_collapsed_flamegraph.svg
Ignored 2335 lines with invalid format
ERROR: No stack counts found
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The following generates an appropriate 10 second sample for process `ProcessName` with an accompanying SVG from having [FlameGraph](https://github.com/brendangregg/FlameGraph) cloned to `~/dev/macos/FlameGraph` and places the outputs in `~/tmp/` with a current timestamp affixed thereunto for uniqueness and easy reference:

```
sudo dtrace -x ustackframes=100 -n 'profile-10ms /execname == "ProcessName"/ { @[ustack()] = count(); } tick-10s { exit(0); }' \
| tee ~/tmp/$(date +"%Y-%m-%d_%H.%M.%S")-ProcessName_sample.txt \
| ~/dev/macos/FlameGraph/stackcollapse.pl \
| ~/dev/macos/FlameGraph/flamegraph.pl \
> ~/tmp/$(date +"%Y-%m-%d_%H.%M.%S")-WindowServer_sample.txt.svg
```

For example, running this on `WindowServer` will produce the following output:

```
2023-02-20_13.06.10-WindowServer_sample.txt.svg
2023-02-20_13.06.10-WindowServer_sample.txt
```

Comment: this looks like it could work, but it would be nice to have a bit more explanation of the arguments provided to dtrace. I'd be curious how we can trace and see a short-lived process, that take ~1.5 s (instead of a few ms). I don't have time to start it and then run `dtrace` in parallel